# How to make output of Matlab m file to stay for a while

Tags: matlab, types, plot, overflow, buffer

I have matlab m file which plots 3 graphs using subplot. Now i also have a UNIX script which invokes this script and passes the function name as parameter.

I have two problems:

1. I am getting the warning Type-ahead buffer Overflow
2. The plot remains only for a few seconds before disappearing. How can I keep plot active til l user clicks on cross button?

thanks!

Comment: Please post sample code. How are you doing what you describe?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's hard to answer your first question without some code.
2. You can use the `pause` command to wait for the user to press any key.